# HTML js and making cookies

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a basic cookie through js in my html. the js has to be in a separate file named javascript.js and in the html I need to call the function to make and store a cookie. I  have

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

before my body to create the source in the file. I have a button trying to call a function getCookie so in my body ive got

```
<button onclick="js.getCookie">COOKIE</button>
```

there should be a popup asking for my name but im not sure why its not working.

the js file

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
}
return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
var user = getCookie("username");
if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
} else {
    user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (user != "" && user != null) {
        setCookie("username", user, 365);
    }
}
}
```

its a basic thing it took from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp because im trying to understand cookies

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. `onclick` property should point to a function. I don't think `js.getCookie` is a valid javascript function. Can you show the content of the js file?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Hit F12 in your browser of choice to view the Developer Tools, which includes the console. If you have console errors, have you tried to fix them and what are they? Most importantly what is in `javascript.js`? Please provide the relevant code from the javascript file. While you're in Browser Tools, use the Network tab to make sure the javascript file is loaded (look for 404 errors)

Comment: Here is a good resource for getting and setting cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: Simply, you are calling the wrong function. Call `checkCookie` not `getCookie` and drop `js.`

Answer (score 0):

When you use an inline js function in your html you also need to have parentheses behind it. I've pasted your code into a snippet and made the function call work.

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var user = getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
  } else {
    user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (user != "" && user != null) {
      setCookie("username", user, 365);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<button onclick="checkCookie();">COOKIE</button>
</body>
```